# How do I remove Samba4.2.0pre which was compiled from source?

Tags: uninstall

I cloned samba from git to samba-master with

`clone git git://git.samba.org/samba.git samba-master`

and did

```
git pull
```

It downloaded from git and I figured I would only get the latest stable version of Samba. I was on 4.0.6 and wanted 4.0.9.

I only want stable versions of Samba, but by mistake I installed Samba 4.2.0pre and now I want to remove it.

How do I do that?

//edit

I first cloned it from git.samba.org into samba-master with the command:

```
git clone git://git.samba.org/samba.git samba-master
```

I then did `cd samba-master` from / and started:

```
./configure --enable-debug --enable-selftest  
make  
make install
```

The install directory is

```
/usr/local/samba
```

I have put the install directory in `/etc/environment`

Comment: Did you try these command in terminal : `sudo apt-get autoremove samba4*` and `sudo apt-get --purge remove samba4*` Reply..

Comment: Largely depends on how you installed it. Can you tell us what you did (***before*** you start `apt-get removing` things on people's advice)? Please edit your questions to include the commands you ran.

Answer (score 4):

The `samba` source compiler might actually have an "uninstall" command as part of the makefile that can remove the software.

Try doing `make uninstall` or `make remove`.  If the makefile was created sanely then it's likely one of those two commands might actually remove the software compiled by the source through `make` and `make install`.

Comment: Per the comment discussion on the other answer, we have determined that `make uninstall` will remove the `samba4.2.0pre` software.  +1 to samba for creating a nice makefile that can also uninstall the software when you want to get rid of it.  :)

Comment: Note it won't clean up the folders... :/

Answer (score 0):

I have learned from ubuntuforums that there is no way to use `apt-get remove samba4`, or `apt-get --purge remove samba4*`to uninstall Samba 4.2.0pre installed from git, because it has not been installed from reposistory.

The only way to uninstall Samba 4.2.0pre installed from git is to do `rm -rf` on the samba folder and to edit all files you edited that referes to Samba 4.2.0pre in the beginning.

Comment: There are other methods for removing, however, to work, it's dependent on how it was installed.  This answer you've provided does not provide a complete answer, because sane programs might also include a `make uninstall` or `make remove` script.

Comment: What you say makes sense, I aggree with you. But this is what I learned from the forum. Every sensible programmer always provides an oppertunity to remove their software.

Comment: Without more information from what you did, we can't really identify whether or not `make remove` or `make uninstall` exists.  Did you try running `make uninstall` or `make remove`?

Comment: No, I didn't even know I could do that.

Comment: Trying those wouldn't hurt, because if the person is sensible they included an option to remove the program with make, however that's something that would require testing.  Otherwise you might have to manually remove the folder and the binaries.

Comment: @Thomas W 
The commands `make uninstall` absolutly works. I just finished uninstalling Samba4.2.0pre with this command.

Comment: awesome, I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: One disturbing thing is that it doesn't clean up after uninstall. All folders are left behind. I see that as a problem.

Comment: Agreed, you can remove the folders after the fact though.